# On click how to go to an another page in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Hi friends i know how to go to an another page in jquery, I need the same in angular js.

```
    $('#leaderboar').on('click',function(){
    document.location.href='HomeScreen.html';
    });
```

Can any one help me out in this.
Thanks

Comment: Need a little more detail about your Angular app: Are you using Angular's built in routing, with either [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) or the [`ui.router` module](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)? Do you want the page to reload on change (i.e. are you working on an SPA)?

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to redirect to a page(as in your jQuery code above) you can use :-

```
$location.path('/home');
```

You can also use $window as below :-

```
$window.location.href = 'HomeScreen.html'
```

From Angular documentation :-

> $location does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href.

Answer (score 0):

$location.path('/other-page');

...

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/other-page', { templateUrl: 'other-page.html', controller: 'PageCtrl' })
```